# JAX-WS Web service on Tomcat without sun-jaxws.xml

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jax-ws

I am trying to minimize required configuration while deploying JAX-WS-based Web service on Tomcat. With the introduction of Servlet 3.0 (supported by Tomcat 7+), `web.xml` can be thrown out, but there is still `sun-jaxws.xml`. This [blog post](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2010/08/13/jax-ws-ri-web-services-deployment-made-simplified) is interesting:

> Of course, with the use of jax-ws annotations, even configuration
>   sun-jaxws.xml can be made optional making it completely descriptor
>   free, but that requires specifying a default url-pattern like in
>   JSR-109 or custom pattern like in Jersey REST services, in the JAX-WS
>   specification.

Is it possible to avoid `sun-jaxws.xml` on Tomcat, and how?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sadly, the configuration **must** exist *somewhere*. That is mandatory, per the source. Believe it or not, [the location of the sun-jaxws.xml file is hard-coded](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.2.7/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/servlet/WSServletContextListener.java#207) to /WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml (thanks, guys @ Metro).

**Effectively, you need to take control of the following classes**

- [`public final class WSServletContextListener`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.2.7/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/servlet/WSServletContextListener.java)
- [`public class WSServlet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.2.7/com/sun/xml/ws/transport/http/servlet/WSServlet.java#WSServlet)

---

**What needs to happen:**

1. `WSServletContextListener` will obviously not be extended. This listener performs most of the initializations per the sun-jaxws.xml and jaxws-catalog file. Like I mentioned earlier, the location is hard coded. So your path of least resistance here is to

   - implement your own vanilla servlet listener (with `@WebListener`) and call a `new WSServletContextListener()`. You'll then delegate your own `contextInitialized(ServletContext ctxt)` and `contextDestroyed()` methods to the ones in your instance of `WSServletContextListener`.
   - Generate the file on instantiation of the listener, on the fly, using an `@XmlRootElement` class that'll represent the sun-jaxws file(I'll provide a sample of this in a short while, don't have the time right now :) ).

It's a lot of trouble for such a dispensable convenience, IMO, but it should work in theory. I'll write some samples and see how they play shortly.

Comment: +1, didn't know that the location of `sun-jaxws.xml` is hard-coded :) What about default url-pattern that should make `sun-jaxws.xml` optional (see the blog I have cited in my question), do you know anything about it?

Comment: @MiljenMikic reading that post carefully, it all seems like a lot of wishful thinking and not much of a reference: The link in his blog post is dead. I still managed to track down the sources he was referring to [here](http://jarvana.com/jarvana/inspect/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-ri/2.2.2-promoted-b03/jaxws-ri-2.2.2-promoted-b03.zip?folder=jaxws-ri/samples/optional_webxml/) and the [readme.txt](http://jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-ri/2.2.2-promoted-b03/jaxws-ri-2.2.2-promoted-b03.zip!/jaxws-ri/samples/optional_webxml/Readme.txt) still indicates a sun-jaxws.xml is necessary

Answer (score 4):

To have JAX-WS support in Tomcat you must configure:

- **WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml**
- **WSServletContextListener**
- **WSServlet**

Unfortunately it is hard to omit the **WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml** file but there is easier way to omit **web.xml** configuration because of Servlet 3.0 API.

You can do something like this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "ServiceServlet" , urlPatterns = "/service", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class Servlet extends WSServlet {

}
```

and

```
@WebListener
public class Listener implements ServletContextAttributeListener, ServletContextListener {

    private final WSServletContextListener listener;

    public Listener() {
        this.listener = new WSServletContextListener();
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeAdded(ServletContextAttributeEvent event) {
        listener.attributeAdded(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeRemoved(ServletContextAttributeEvent event) {
        listener.attributeRemoved(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeReplaced(ServletContextAttributeEvent event) {
        listener.attributeReplaced(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        listener.contextInitialized(sce);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        listener.contextDestroyed(sce);
    }
}
```

I have tested it on Tomcat-8.5.23 version and it works. But remember that you still must have **WEB-INF/sun-jaxws.xml** file.

```
<endpoints xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
       version="2.0">
    <endpoint name="SampleService"
          implementation="com.ws.ServiceImpl"
          url-pattern="/service" />
</endpoints>
```

Comment: I am aware that we can omit `web.xml` file, that is already mentioned in the text of the question. The question is about omitting `sun-jaxws.xml` file.

Comment: Ahh okay but I added the solution for other people that might not know how to omit web.xml file for this problem. For example I had that problem several weeks ago.

Comment: is there any way we can specify port in this xml configuration ?

Comment: what is implementation="com.ws.ServiceImpl"
in this example?

Answer (score 2):

I have publised web services successfully by this way. I have used  apache cfx for publishing in servletContextListener.

```
@WebListener
public class WebServicePublisListener implements ServletContextListener {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public WebServicePublisListener() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see ServletContextListener#contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent)
     */
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)  { 
        JaxWsServerFactoryBean srvFactory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
        srvFactory.setServiceClass(RandService.class);
        srvFactory.setAddress("/RandService");
        srvFactory.setServiceBean(new RandServiceImplement());
        srvFactory.create();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have tagged my question with "JAX-WS RI" or "Metro" tags, since `sun-jaxws.xml` is related to these implementations. Apache CXF is different implementation of JAX-WS, so it does not have nothing with `sun-jaxws.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to publish the web service. You can implement a ServletContextListener and publish the endpoint:

```
@javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener 
public class AppServletContextListener implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) { 
        Endpoint.publish("{protocol}://{host}:{port}/{context}/{wsName}", new MyHelloWorldWSImpl());
    } 

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) { 
        .... 
    }
}
```

sun-jaxws.xml is not mandatory by specs...If you note, for example, glassfish (metro) makes it optional. Also, if you expose a EJB 3.1 as webservice (with jaxws) you can see no sun-jaxws.xml file in the generated build.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I don't want to use Endpoint.publish(..) infrastructure because it represents a lightweight HTTP server - if I wanted that, I wouldn't have used Tomcat. Next, Tomcat is a servlet container; in other words you cannot deploy EJBs on Tomcat. I'm aware that works like a charm in Glassfish, but that's because Glassfish is JSR-109-compliant.

Comment: Tomcat does not supports EJB by default. You should consider using, for instance, TomEE. I mentioned EJB just to act as a example to demonstrate no needs of sun-jaxws.xml (It's not mandatory).

Comment: Personally, I would always prefer full application server (such as Glassfish) over servlet container (such as Tomcat). But, our clients use Tomcat and I am curious if it's possible to simplify a configuration needed for the deployment of Web services on Tomcat. Therefore, my question is specifically about Tomcat, not TomEE or Glassfish.