# jax-ws not able to get the wsdl, sun-jaxws.xml might be wrong?

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

I developed a first service, it was working great.  Now I am developing another similar service.  When I manually publish the endpoint, i could browse the wsdl.  But when I deployed the ear file to JBoss, I am not able to see the wsdl.  EAR deployed to JBoss successfully, i see the status as UP and running.

Here is my sun-jaxws.xml file.  I expect wsdl lto be deployed to url:port/services/Lookup?wsdl.  right?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<endpoints xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime' version='2.0'>
    <endpoint
            name='LookupService'
            implementation='com.company.it.webservices.LookupService'
            url-pattern='/services/Lookup'/>
</endpoints>
```

Here is my web.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
           version="2.5">

   <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <description>JAX-WS endpoint</description>
        <display-name>WSServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>WSServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WSServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

TIA for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the contents of the web.xml file but keep the file it self. To tell the truth I have no idea why this is the case but WS that are deployed to JBoss do not work otherwise.

Comment: No, it did not work.  Any way to debug and get the correct URL for the WSDL on JBoss?

Comment: and any detail documentation which discuss about web.xml sun-jaxws.xml files?

Comment: Hmm... no. Although I usually deploy web services using WAR archive and have no sun-jaxws.xml at all (while keeping web.xml empty).

Comment: Then how does it know where to deploy the wsdl? like services/Loookup?

Comment: As I said, I have no idea how this works (just that it works). I assume it uses the implementation file to check this but do not quote me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old post may but people who reach here to find solution for their it problem helps, ok, solution to this problem is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581751/sun-jaxws-xml-when-is-it-needed-and-when-not),

How it works ? JAX WS reference implementation ships with `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener` and `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet` these classes take care of serving the request. If you are familiar with web.xml it is very easy to understand.